# Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: android-studio

the problem is happening when i click build apk.i cannot resolve the problem.please help me out.i will be thankful to you...thanks in advance. here is some necessary photos.

C:\Users\STAR.android\build-cache\57f0d2054ad5c8607eba417fe51bc17e246b7c74\output\res\values-in\values.xml

[image: this is a screenshot of that error screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot you provide the problem arises from values.xml files inside res/values folder, which should not be there. values is the name of your folder(s) inside which you put strings.xml, colors.xml, styles.xml.